PowerBI getting results by grouping in the related table
I have 3 tables:

contains team code, position name and number of people
contains team code and team name
contains list of people with their names, team code, position name and various other information like marital situation, etc

I have connected table 1 with table 2 and table 3 with table 1 by team code (one to many).
Now I need to create a table, which would contain team code, position name and 3 calculated columns ('Single', 'Married', 'Divorced') with an amount of people, which have such words in their 'marital situation' column.
Tried some DAX code using sumx, but it looks that in gives only a number of people in that team.
How can I achieve such a grouping and calculation?

Update/Edit your question above to include the DAX that you have tried. Even better would be to also include sample rows of each table in markdown format, together with the expected results.

I added each of the following calculated columns to the Teams Table.
Single = 

VAR thisTeam = Teams[Team Code]

RETURN CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(ALLSELECTED(People))
    , People[Marital Situation] = "Single"
    , People[Team Code] = thisTeam
) + 0

Married = 

VAR thisTeam = Teams[Team Code]

RETURN CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(ALLSELECTED(People))
    , People[Marital Situation] = "Married"
    , People[Team Code] = thisTeam
) + 0

Divorced = 

VAR thisTeam = Teams[Team Code]

RETURN CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(ALLSELECTED(People))
    , People[Marital Situation] = "Divorced"
    , People[Team Code] = thisTeam
) + 0

Output:


Mock data used:
Table 1: Team Positions



Team Code
Position Name
Number of People




T001
Developer
5


T002
Designer
3


T003
Tester
4


T004
Manager
2



Table 2: Teams



Team Code
Team Name




T001
Alpha Team


T002
Beta Team


T003
Gamma Team


T004
Delta Team



Table 3: People



Person Name
Team Code
Position Name
Marital Situation




Alice
T001
Developer
Single


Bob
T001
Developer
Married


Charlie
T002
Designer
Divorced


Dave
T003
Tester
Married


Eva
T003
Tester
Single


Frank
T004
Manager
Divorced


Grace
T002
Designer
Single


Helen
T004
Manager
Married



